# Regex to replace relative link with root relative link

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a string of text that contains html with all different types of links (relative, absolute, root-relative). I need a regex that can be executed by PHP's `preg_replace` to replace all relative links with root-relative links, without touching any of the other links. I have the root path already.

Replaced links:

```
<tag ... href="path/to_file.ext" ... >   --->   <tag ... href="/basepath/path/to_file.ext" ... >
<tag ... href="path/to_file.ext" ... />   --->   <tag ... href="/basepath/path/to_file.ext" ... />
```

Untouched links:

```
<tag ... href="/any/path" ... >
<tag ... href="/any/path" ... />
<tag ... href="protocol://domain.com/any/path" ... >
<tag ... href="protocol://domain.com/any/path" ... />
```

Comment: Must it be regex? Using a DOM class could allow much more accurate results.

Comment: It must be regex as I have no assurance that DOM will be valid enough for any basic DOM reader to parse correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to change the base URI, you can try the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE):

```
<base href="/basepath/">
```

But note that changing the base URI affects *all* relative URIs and not just relative URI paths.

Otherwise, if you really want to use regular expression, consider that a relative path like you want must be of the type *path-noscheme* (see [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)):

> ```
> path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
> segment       = *pchar
> segment-nz-nc = 1*( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / "@" )
>                 ; non-zero-length segment without any colon ":"
> pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
> pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
> unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

So the begin of the URI must match:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=@]|%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+($|/)
```

But please use a proper HTML parser for parsing the HTML an build a DOM out of that. Then you can query the DOM to get the `href` attributes and test the value with the regular expression above.

Comment: the base tag worked almost perfectly except it seems to mess with links such as href="#test" it turns them into href="/basepath/#test". On the up side, href="link#test" turns into href="/basepath/link#test", which works. Is there a way for anchors to work with the base class, without knowing anything current url?

Comment: The above comment is actually a bug in webkit (safari, chrome) and IE, it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @Kendall Hopkins: Just as I said: *all* relative URIs are affected. And `#test` is a relative URI. And I would rather say it’s a bug in Firefox not to resolve `#test` with a base URI of `/basepath/` to `/basepath/#test`. (I think Firefox uses the algorithm of RFC 2396 while the others use the one of RFC 3986 that obsoleted RFC 3986 five years ago.)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
preg_replace('#href=["\']([^/][^\':"]*)["\']#', $root_path.'$1', $html);
```

It might be a little too simplistic. The obvious flaw I see is that it will also match `href="something"` when it is outside of a tag, but hopefully it can get you started.